# Invalid flags → disputed → flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies. What?

Tags: support, flagging, 10k-tools

I continue to be befuddled by what exactly one is supposed to do with flags in the 10k tools, and I'm quite relieved to know [they're going away soon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226092/lets-get-rid-of-the-10k-flag-queue). In the meantime, though, here's a stumper I just came across in my flagging history:

[image]

The post in question is [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/104304/without-seeing-the-lightning-can-you-tell-how-far-away-it-struck-by-how-the-thu/104308#104308), which came up flagged as Not an Answer if I remember correctly. I understand why someone would flag this - it was only a sort-of good fit to the question to begin with - but I disagree that it failed to address the original intent of the OP. Particularly, I felt it did answer the question in its state at the time, with a less specific title.

On the other hand, given the current state of the question, I can understand that it might best be classed as Not an Answer. Given that, I can understand that my `invalid flags` is disputed.

I'm completely stumped, however, at the message. `Flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer`? That has absolutely nothing to do with why I flagged this way. The technical content of the post was never an issue.

Could someone elucidate what on Earth this message means and how it came into being?

Answer (score 5):

Invalid flags are dismissed with the same reason as the original ones. So they automatically get marked as disputed -- this means the *original* flag was disputed, not your invalid flag.

So what happened here was: User A flagged a post. You invalid flag-flagged it. Then, a moderator declined the original flag (automatically declining the invalid flag), with that message. If a 10k user marks as invalid, the final outcome is always "disputed", IIRC. It's confusing, yes, but going away soon.

Comment: I believe I read that there is now a mechanism to deal with flags one at a time, though I haven't figured out how to do it yet...

Comment: @dmckee i think it only applies to certain types of flags.

Comment: So, in other words, exactly the opposite of what should have happened? I'm so glad this is going away.

Comment: I take it this means all my disputed invalid-flags flags are actually all right, then.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty more or less :P When you flag as invalid you're supposed to ignore the feedback message as it's never meant for you.

Comment: Hmmm. How, though, am I supposed to find that out? Was there a manual I should have read? Overall, not the pinnacle of SE user interface design.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty nope, it isn't. I have complained about it before, as have others. Now it will be fixed :)